# What is the thing in KDE that override my locale settings

Tags: kubuntu, kde, locale

With Kubuntu 14.04, I have got some trouble with the locales. "Something" in KDE override my settings (I say in KDE because if I use gnome, I got no problems).

Here are my settings

```
$ cat /etc/default/locale 
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.UTF-8"


$ cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

But I got (the problem are the "en_FR.UTF-8"):

```
$ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_FR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_FR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_FR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_FR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_FR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_FR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_FR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_FR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_FR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

What do you think of that?

Thanks!

Comment: Over SSH some environment variables are sent/accepted as per your ssh_config / sshd_config. That is not KDE specific at all. Your processes in your KDE session are inheriting from the KDE session process setting the locale settings based on your user's preference in system settings. What is exactly the issue? These are just settings in System Settings (in KDE).

Comment: Ok for ssh, I edited my question. Then the problem is to find what in kde messes up my settings by setting some "en_FR.UTF-8", and how to configure/disable it in command line (I tried the graphical system settings/locale, with no success)? Thanks

Comment: Please post the output of `cat ~/.kde/env/setlocale.sh`. This is a script generated by the system settings of KDE. If it contains FR locales and you did not set it to French in system settings you are probably not using the right KDE system settings panel, but the Gnome settings in your KDE session.

Comment: @gertvdijk: This is most certainly KDE specific. I wrote bug [#1395401](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1395401) a while ago, and I think this is the same issue.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I've read the question wrong I guess. What I missed was that the locale specified is nonexistent, wrong. So, yes, OP probably is hit by the same bug. For SSH just disable the LC env to be sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I erased the content of ~/.kde/env/setlocale.sh, and it works!

Tkanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe better workaround for this is clearing setlocale.sh and setting it as read only file with:

```
cd ~/.kde/env/setlocale.sh
> setlocale.sh
chmod 444 setlocale.sh
```

now you would be ignoring completely settings in GUI and will have working settings from:

```
/etc/default/locale
```