# Fixing missing locales

Tags: kubuntu, locale

I've been experiencing some `locale` issues lately. I first noticed it when trying to run calibre from the terminal.

Running `calibre` returned:

`WARNING: Failed to set default libc locale, using en_US.UTF-8`

Then I ran `locale` which gave:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_NZ.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

After some [research](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue) I found that the file `/etc/environment` might need something added to it, but I got confused because its content seems not related at all:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

How can I fix this issue? I am running Kubuntu 17.10.

**EDIT**: I found the file `/etc/default/locale` which contains the more promissing :

```
    #  File generated by update-locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
```

Is this how it should look?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the thing in KDE that override my locale settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635117/what-is-the-thing-in-kde-that-override-my-locale-settings)

Comment: thanks for your comment. Unfortuanately, I dont have the directory specified in that accepted answer and the file doesn#t exist on my system at all...

Comment: Ok, please see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment I pointed you to [What is the thing in KDE that override my locale settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635117/what-is-the-thing-in-kde-that-override-my-locale-settings), but you let us know that the file `~/.kde/env/setlocale.sh` is not present on your machine.

I still think this problem is related to Kubuntu/KDE somehow. The `locale` output includes the locale name `en_DE.UTF-8`, which does not exist, and that's the reason for the error message.

So I'd advise you to go to Kubuntu's language settings GUI. Probably you have stated *English* as language and *Germany* as country, which unfortunately leads Kubuntu to set this non-existing locale. Try for instance to change the country to *Denmark*, and then relogin. Hopefully that will set the locale `en_DK.UTF-8` (which exists) instead.

The issue has been reported as [bug #1322968](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1322968).

Comment: Brilliant! That did the trick.  In the KDE "Formats" GUI I seelcted 'Germany-English (en_DE)'. I corrected it to 'Deutschland-Deutsch (de_DE)' and after reboot everything resolved. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this thread? [How do I fix my locale issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue)
This helps me on some of the missing locales see if this works for you.

Comment: This case is probably specific to Kubuntu/KDE; see the suggested duplicate bug.

Answer (score -2):

Try:`sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`

Comment: Given that `en_DE.UTF-8` does not exist in `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED`, how would that help?

Comment: I update my answer

Comment: If this not solving your problem it seems that something has been removed

Comment: No, you misunderstood me. The thing is that a locale name which does not exist in `glibc` is being set, so even if you regenerate the locales, no `en_DE.UTF-8` locale will be created, and the error won't go away. (Excluding the `-u` option doesn't make a difference in this respect.)

Comment: I see, i will search if i can find something useful to answer